# Effect of temperature on benzenediazonium during diazotization

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

What will benezendiazonium ion become if it is not maintained at a temperature below $5\ °\mathrm{C}$ during diazotization?

Comment: I have done to much editing as it was flagged as low quality. If you feel it's not proper you can rollback.

Comment: I don't know what is "diazodization" I think it should be "diazotization" but did not edited as i wasn't sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Diazonium salts are prone to ejection of molecular nitrogen. The process is fairly slow for aromatic diazonium salts, so the salts are usually relatively stable around 0 celsius (alkyldiazonium salsts, though, are a completely different matter). In case of benzenediazonium resulting phenyl-cation is extremely active and will react with first nucleophile present, in many cases it is water, so the product would be phenol.