# What is the effect of NaNO2/HCl at 0-5° C on Nitro group?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, organic-reduction

In this particular reaction firstly $\ce{NaNO2/HCl}$ at $\pu{0-5°C}$ was taken and after that $\ce{H2/Ni}$ .

But what I doubt is, was there any role of $\ce{NaNO2/HCl}$ at $\pu{0-5°C}$ ?
Since only reduction occurred which can also be done by $\ce{H2/Ni}$[image]

Comment: The only way this works is if the reduction is carried out in the presence of HNO2. Looks like whoever wrote this reversed the stages.

Comment: @Waylander this was asked in a national exam

Comment: HNO2 will have no effect on the starting material. Either the reaction scheme is incorrect, or it is poorly expressed and is meant to depict hydrogenation over Raney Nickel IN THE PRESENCE OF HNO2

Comment: @Waylander so what is effect of this reduction being carried out in presence of HNO2 ?? Will it go as usual or will have any other effect

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/why-should-the-temperature-be-maintained-at-0-5-c-in-a-diazotisation/76550 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/effect-of-temperature-on-benzenediazonium-during-diazotization

Comment: @MridulKumar if the reaction scheme is correct then the HNO2 has had no effect.

Comment: @MridulKumar  indeed if the diazonium species were formed I rather suspect it would be reduced by H2/Ni